# Why can't I fetch Mongoid documents using my old _id format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a model in a Rails/Mongoid application that I had initially set a key using `key: uid` (where :uid is an attribute)

I am removing this so that the model reverts to using the default _id format. However the existing objects are not reflecting this change.

for example for an object with uid: 507, the _id is still 507. thus I am able to retrieve it using `Testobjects.where(_id: "507")`

however, `Testobjects.find("507")` returns `BSON::InvalidObjectId: illegal ObjectId format`

(using `BSON::ObjectId('507')` gives the same error)

so now I am unable to retrieve old objects using find (because it's not recognizing their _id, and I can't retrieve a new _id)

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your old keys were probably strings or integers, not BSON::ObjectId instances. You might need to write a migration that makes them consistent, [**because earlier versions of Mongoid didn't typecast the id**](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/545).

Comment: thanks, was hoping for a more integrated solution but that works as well!